# How to call a controller in spring MVC after clicking on anchor tag in html

Tags: spring-mvc, controller, request-mapping

how can i call a spring  MVC controller with request Mapping say ("/example") after clicking on a anchor tag in html??

Comment: Maybe show us what you have tried until now...

Comment: Nothing much but i just have a controller in which i have a method with request mapping ("showresults") and i have created a  demo jsp file. i have a anchor tag there , i want to click on that anchor tag and call that method with requestmapping ("showresults")

Comment: Which View technology or View resolver are you using? if you'd be using `jsp` then you could simply do this :


`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>`


`<a href="<spring:url value='/example' />" >Go to Example</a>`

Comment: Post your controller class. You could wrap the anchor tag in a form to handle the submission.

Comment: `<spring:url value='/example' />` so request mapping should be ("/example")